# Use pickAFile delete file path but keep file name Python

Tags: python, string, file, jython

I have a file am I getting by using `pickAFile()` when I print the file from this code `file = pickAFile()` I get this "C:\Users\jake\Documents\files\DataFiles\pandas.txt". How do I delete the file path but keep the file name? IE I want to keep "pandas.txt" in the string but everything before that I don't want.

Note: I want to be able to do this for files with different name lengths and without using imported libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print r"C:\Users\jake\Documents\files\DataFiles\pandas.txt".split("\\")[-1]
print r"C:\Users\whom\content.bmp".split("\\")[-1]
print r"C:\Users\jake\Documents\cats.txt".split("\\")[-1]
```

Your question being very unclear I assumed this is what you wanted.
Without the use of any modules you can split the string on a common divider in this scenario. `.split("\\")` will split the string on the `\` character which needs to be escaped, otherwise it will escape the closing quote. `[-1]` will get the last element of the just created list.

```
>>> pandas.txt
>>> content.bmp
>>> cats.txt
```

To make things easier consider putting it in a function or merging it with a already existing function

```
def f(string, ifs="\\"):
    return unicode(string).split(ifs)[-1]

print f("A\B\C\D\E")
>>> E
print f("A/B/C/D/E",ifs="/")
>>> E
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying! Yeah that is what im looking to do. So i dont want to type the string into the code you put there, is it possible for it to take the file instead of it typing out the string in there? something like `print rFile.split("\\")[-1]` where file is the string?

Comment: This is insanely confusing. But If you mean that `pickAFile()` returns a string. You would have to do `print f(pickAFile())`.